# how make fileoutputstream not add a blank line on every write or on every line of a report

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a spool file to text when I try converting it but it adds a blank line after each line of writing(sorry if that did not make any sense)

```
                PrintObjectTransformedInputStream txtInStream = spooledFile.getTransformedInputStream(plist);
                txtInStream = spooledFile.getTransformedInputStream(plist);

                spooledFile.getStringAttribute(PrintObject.ATTR_CODEPAGE);

                if(txtInStream != null) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
                    fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

                    int bytesRead = 0;

                    while ((bytesRead = txtInStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                        fileoutputstream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    fileoutputstream.close();
                    txtInStream.close();
                }
```

here is the small part where it writes if anyone has any idea on how I can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If the newline is coming from the source document you could use a simple solution line

```
if(buffer[0]!=new String("\n").getBytes()[0])
    fileoutputstream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Comment: The new line is not coming from the source document. In the source document does not have a blank line in between.